# How can i get this probability?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I've been solving some problems and i'm stuck with this one:

A business woman in Philadelphia is preparing an itinerary for a visit to six major cities. The distance traveled, and hence the cost of the trip, will depend on the order in which she plans the route.

a) How many different itineraries are possible?

b) If the business woman selects one of the possible itineraries and Denver and San Francisco are two of the cities she plans to visit, what is the probability she will visit Denver before San Francisco?

For a) is easy to say that there are $6! = 720$ posible itineraries.

But for b) i can't think of any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wen is completely right:

$ p= \frac {1}{6}( 1+ \frac 4 5 +  \frac 3 5+ \frac 2 5+ \frac 1 5 ) = \frac 1 2 $

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking.

Comment: There are 6 cities. Probability Denver first is 1/6...then San francisco after Denver is 1 its a certitude...and so on.....  probability Denver second city visited..1/6 and San Francisco after Denver ? 4/5...so on then it gives the correct answer 1/2

Answer (score 2):

The probability is half since the chance of visiting Denver first is *exactly* the same as the chance of visiting San Fransisco first.

Comment: Can you explain how do i get to that? I need help getting the combination of those outcomes.

Comment: The question is symmetric in Denver and San Fransisco; this means that changing their names over in the question does not change the final answer. But then since either Denver or San Fransisco must come first, their probabilities must add to 1